# Enable layered navigation in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1 and i am working on layered navigation. but when i am going to edit the option of attribute, i find that the the layered navigation option is not enable to edit.

[image]

i tried a lot to find how to enable this but i failed.

```
       <input disabled="" id="position" name="position" value="0" title="Position      in Layered Navigation" class="validate-digits input-text" type="text">
```

may be this is the problem, but where is this code, i am not able to find it.

i tried so many free extension also but after that also this is not enable on frontend.

please help me and tell me what to do.

Comment: Hey user2963674,

Please post screenshots of your attribute settings. Some settings are not able to be filtered by the default classes provided with Magento CE 1.8.1. Also please list the extensions you tried. There are some badly written extensions out there that modify database data they shouldn't.

Comment: Can you write here attribute type ? Is it text, dropdown or ?

Comment: hi, thanx for reply. i am done this by creating new attribute and selecting dropdown option. but now also it is not enable on frontend. in cofiguration it is enabled but is there any thing else to do?

Answer (score 0):

In native magento only dropdown (as I remember) and price can be used in layered navigation.

Here is an example of customization how to allow type=text use for LN (I didn't check if this solution 100% workable): https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4883/text-attribute-in-the-layered-navigation